# Place order button not working with stripe stored credit cards Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, stripe

I've integrated stripe as payment method in onepagecheckout magento 2
But seems something wrong as "Place order" button is not working with the "Stored stripe cc cards"
https://prnt.sc/rp70pl
"Place order" button is clickable , although it sends request to payment-information api
but order does'nt get placed.
Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: check console. Is there any error message?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method_code' of null
    at Object.module.saveShippingInformation (default.js:70)
    at Object.saveShippingInformation (shipping-save-processor.js:37)
    at set-shipping-information.js:16
    at payment.js:74

Comment: I think you are getting the error because of shipping method code. Check this code  `quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'],` in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js`

Comment: Kunj ,i've solved this  , still same issue place order is not working , it works when i change the payment method and reselect the payment method . https://prnt.sc/rp8duh

Comment: there would be something in payment method JS file which is missing. I can not assume why it is not working without that module source/ test credentials or error.

Comment: Thank you Kunj , seems like need to dubug more.

Comment: what is the meaning of this -> data_id: 1585552198 ? This one is found in cache storage obj

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal how did you solve? I have the same problem

Comment: I had solved this issue. The payment code also needs to be set of the stored stripe card.